# Clarification YouTube Data API v3 Quotas

Tags: youtube-data-api, quota

I have a Google project created on the [Google developer console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=gathervideo). This project retrieves information about all content on my channel (livestreams and posted videos) and keeps statistics updated for each one.  The processes that gather this information run three times per day.  I would like to run them more frequently, but after a total of 300 quota, I receive the dreaded error 403 that says,

```
The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your <a href="/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota">quota</a>
```

Here is a today's usage summary as an example:

```
+------------+---------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+-------+-----------+--------+
| callDate   | calledBy                                    | serviceName                        | calls | totalCost | failed |
+------------+---------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+-------+-----------+--------+
| 2022-04-14 | /www/htdocs/GetChats/someoneSingsVideos.php | search->listSearch                 |    53 |       106 |      3 |
| 2022-04-14 | /www/htdocs/GetChats/someoneSingsVideos.php | videos->listVideos                 |    50 |        50 |   NULL |
| 2022-04-14 | /www/htdocs/GetChats/lives.php              | liveBroadcasts->listLiveBroadcasts |    10 |        10 |   NULL |
| 2022-04-14 | /www/htdocs/GetChats/videos.php             | search->listSearch                 |    48 |        96 |   NULL |
| 2022-04-14 | /www/htdocs/GetChats/videos.php             | videos->listVideos                 |    48 |        48 |   NULL |
| 2022-04-14 | /www/htdocs/GetChats/someoneSingsVideos.php | --program total--                  |   103 |       156 |      3 |
| 2022-04-14 | /www/htdocs/GetChats/lives.php              | --program total--                  |    10 |        10 |   NULL |
| 2022-04-14 | /www/htdocs/GetChats/videos.php             | --program total--                  |    96 |       144 |   NULL |
| 2022-04-14 | --day total--                               |                                    |   209 |       310 |      3 |
+------------+---------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+-------+-----------+--------+
```

So in essence, I can get about 50 searches and about 100 list calls done in a day... then I have to wait 24 hours to try again.  But when I check my quotas and their usage at the [IAM Admin Quotas page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas), I see a very different result:
[image]

This page, intended to clarify API Quotas and their usage, just adds questions for me.  For example, at face value, looks like there is a 10,000 quota-units limit per day but I can do 1.8M per minute.  Clearly both cannot be true.  But morr to the point, it seems to indicate that i'm way below my legal limit although it issues that error and stops me until the next day, after that 300 quota is reached.

Can anyone help me understand what the real limits are, and maybe help me understand why I must keep my usage so low?